# mysql sum total number of rows by customerid show desc order

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a question my professor gave me, on making a statement that goes like this

**How many customers are “whales” i.e., have spent, in their lifetime, more than $4,000? How many are “shrimps,” having spent less than $20?**

This is the online database we are using: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

run this query to create another table before helping me out if you can

```
CREATE TABLE ByCustomerOrders AS
SELECT
 o.OrderID
, p.ProductName
, p.ProductID
, Price
, Quantity
, Price * Quantity AS subtotal
, c.CustomerID
, s.SupplierID
FROM OrderDetails AS od
LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
LEFT JOIN Products AS p
ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Customers AS c 
on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Suppliers AS s 
ON s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID;
```

I am trying to combine every customers order together grouping the sum by the customerID and then showing it in the table as a row for each customer ID and total amount they have order from subtotal

```
SELECT customerID, SUM(subtotal) AS 'total_money_spent' FROM ByCustomerOrders GROUP BY customerID ORDER BY 'total_money_spent' DESC LIMIT 1;
```

That didn't seem to work as it shows a value of 111. anyone see an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a LIMIT 1 at the end of your statement which will only show the first result.

When you run:
SELECT customerID, SUM(subtotal) AS 'total_money_spent' FROM ByCustomerOrders GROUP BY customerID ORDER BY 'total_money_spent' DESC;

It outputs all the totals grouped

Comment: How would i order it by the total_money_spent, it seems to not be listing it by that? http://i.imgur.com/vJmfDCp.png

Comment: maybe something like this? `SELECT *, SUM(subtotal) AS totalordered FROM ByCustomerOrders GROUP BY customerid HAVING COUNT(totalordered) >= 4000`

Comment: SELECT customerID, SUM(subtotal) AS 'total_money_spent' FROM ByCustomerOrders GROUP BY customerID ORDER BY total_money_spent DESC;

Comment: remove the single quotes around total_money_spent after your ORDER BY

Comment: `SELECT customerID,SUM(subtotal) AS total FROM ByCustomerOrders GROUP BY customerID ORDER BY total desc;` was what i came up with, EDIT: IT MATCHES YOURS, now how do I only list the rows with the sum over 4000? I tried adding **HAVING COUNT(totalordered) >= 4000**

Comment: Add WHERE total_money_spent >= 4000

Comment: I tried `SELECT customerID,SUM(subtotal) AS total_money_spent FROM ByCustomerOrders WHERE total_money_spent >= 4000 GROUP BY customerID ORDER BY total_money_spent desc;` that but it gives me an error: **could not prepare statment: 1 misuse of aggregate SUM()**

Comment: This should do it. SELECT customerID, SUM(subtotal) AS 'total_money_spent' FROM ByCustomerOrders GROUP BY customerID HAVING total_money_spent >= 4000 ORDER BY total_money_spent DESC